# servlet is not called when condtion is met in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am performing add to cart in java script which should call servlet addtocart.jlc as shown below.

```
<%@page import = "java.util.*" %>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h1>JLC book store</h1>
<h2>JLC book search</h2>
<font color = "green" size = '6'> ${ADDED}</font>
</center>
<br/>
<%Object obj = request.getAttribute("MSG");
  if(obj != null) { // if condtion
      %>
      <br/> <center>
            <font color = "red" size = "6">  
             <%=obj%>
            </font>
            <br/><a href = "index.jsp"> 
            <h2> GO TO SEARCH PAGE1 </h2></a>
            </center>
   <%} else { // if condition end and else condition open
       obj = session.getAttribute("BOOKS");
       ArrayList<String> blist = (ArrayList<String>)obj;
       for(String bnm:blist) { 
   %>
   <form action="addtocart.jlc" method="post">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "bname" 
     value = "<%=bnm%>" />
   <font size = '5'> <%=bnm%> <input type = "submit" 
       value = "ADD TO CART" />
   </font>
   </form>
   <% } %> 
   <form action = "showcart.jlc">
   <input type = "submit" value = "SHOW CART" /> 
   </form>
   <% } %> 


</body>
</html>
```

when I ran above program I am getting output as shown below which is in if condition. I am not getting what is error. I am new to jsp and this is print out given by my lecture. I am working on but not able to get what is bug. I am using eclipse EE and tom cat server.

JLC book store
JLC book search
 No books found with categorynull

GO TO SEARCH PAGE1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output I can see that at some point during this request, "No books found with categorynull" has been set to the "MSG" attribute of your request. Try to follow back before the request reaches this file.

I don't know what the .jlc extension is but from the looks of it this is a .jsp file, so your request might have gone through a HttpServlet before reaching this point where

```
request.setAttribute("MSG", "No books found with categorynull");
```

was called.

Also the error message suggests that this request was required to be called with a ?category=xxx query, and the same servlet was supposed to get the list of books for that category and call

```
request.setAttribute("BOOKS", ...);
```

If I were you I would perform a text search in the entire source code for the string .setAttribute("BOOKS"